# Trapcode sphere

Tags: after-effects

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this effect on After Effects with Trapcode Form plugin, because it's particles around the edges with hollow center, I thought it's got to be the spherical field, so I created box-string base form and cranked up the spherical field and I ended up with similar result
[image]

how ever soon I realized the strings around the circle is in segments rather than a continuous line, it becomes more obvious when it's in motion, I'm curious to know how it's supposed to be done, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The "Ring Emitter" preset in Trapcode Particular gets pretty close to this - you could probably use it as a starting point.

Look in the Presets tab on the left under "Spline Primitives".

[image: screengrab]